# Parsing API Response in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, ebay-api

all - hoping you can help me learn how to parse a JSON response.

I have a service that makes an API call like this:

```
  private REST_API_SERVER = 'myapicall.com'

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public sendGetRequest(): Observable<any> {
   return this.httpClient.get(this.REST_API_SERVER);
  }
```

The above is returned to a component:

```
 sendGetRequest(): void {
     this.dataService.sendGetRequest()
       .subscribe(data => this.data = data);

}
```

I can output the response in my component HTML like this:

```
{{data | json}}
```

At which point a response with a structure like this is written to the screen:

```
 {
  "findItemsByKeywordsResponse": [
    {
      "ack": [
        "Success"
      ],
      "version": [
        "1.13.0"
      ],
      "timestamp": [
        "2022-03-03T16:12:06.220Z"
      ],
      "searchResult": [
        {
          "@count": "1",
          "item": [
            {
              "itemId": [
                "294786675398"
              ],
              "title": [
                "Apple iPhone 12 mini (5G) Factory Unlocked GSM+CDMA 256GB | 128GB | 64GB"
              ],
              "globalId": [
                "EBAY-US"
              ],
              "subtitle": [
                "✤Cheapest Online ✤FREE SHIPPING ✤FREE RETURN ✤US SELLER"
              ],
              "primaryCategory": [
                {
                  "categoryId": [
                    "9355"
                  ],
                  "categoryName": [
                    "Cell Phones & Smartphones"
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "galleryURL": [
                "https://i.ebayimg.com/thumbs/images/g/hBYAAOSw~qhgy8mG/s-l140.jpg"
              ],
              "viewItemURL": [
                "https://www.ebay.com/itm/Apple-iPhone-12-mini-5G-Factory-Unlocked-GSM-CDMA-256GB-128GB-64GB-/294786675398?var=593157879172"
              ],
              "autoPay": [
                "true"
              ],
              "postalCode": [
                "112**"
              ],
              "location": [
                "Brooklyn,NY,USA"
              ],
              "country": [
                "US"
              ],
              "shippingInfo": [
                {
                  "shippingServiceCost": [
                    {
                      "@currencyId": "USD",
                      "__value__": "0.0"
                    }
                  ],
                  "shippingType": [
                    "Free"
                  ],
                  "shipToLocations": [
                    "Worldwide"
                  ],
                  "expeditedShipping": [
                    "true"
                  ],
                  "oneDayShippingAvailable": [
                    "true"
                  ],
                  "handlingTime": [
                    "1"
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "sellingStatus": [
                {
                  "currentPrice": [
                    {
                      "@currencyId": "USD",
                      "__value__": "439.88"
                    }
                  ],
                  "convertedCurrentPrice": [
                    {
                      "@currencyId": "USD",
                      "__value__": "439.88"
                    }
                  ],
                  "sellingState": [
                    "Active"
                  ],
                  "timeLeft": [
                    "P28DT9H52M53S"
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "listingInfo": [
                {
                  "bestOfferEnabled": [
                    "false"
                  ],
                  "buyItNowAvailable": [
                    "false"
                  ],
                  "startTime": [
                    "2022-02-01T02:05:58.000Z"
                  ],
                  "endTime": [
                    "2022-04-01T02:04:59.000Z"
                  ],
                  "listingType": [
                    "FixedPrice"
                  ],
                  "gift": [
                    "false"
                  ],
                  "watchCount": [
                    "26"
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "returnsAccepted": [
                "true"
              ],
              "condition": [
                {
                  "conditionId": [
                    "1500"
                  ],
                  "conditionDisplayName": [
                    "Open box"
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "isMultiVariationListing": [
                "true"
              ],
              "topRatedListing": [
                "true"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "paginationOutput": [
        {
          "pageNumber": [
            "1"
          ],
          "entriesPerPage": [
            "1"
          ],
          "totalPages": [
            "12825623"
          ],
          "totalEntries": [
            "12825623"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "itemSearchURL": [
        "https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=iPhone&_ddo=1&_ipg=1&_pgn=1"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In my component HTML, how would I write this item's title to the screen?

Comment: `data.findItemsByKeywordsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item[0].title` is that it??

Comment: @Antoniossss - No, I get a response that 'findItemsByKeywordsResponse' doesn't exist on my service?

Comment: Its part of `data` not your service

Comment: @Antoniossss - correct, but this is the error I get when I try to use that code:

Property 'findItemsByKeywordsResponse' does not exist on type 'EbayDataService'.

Comment: and is `data` a `EbayDataService`??

Comment: Man, I don't know...I'm a noob at this. How could I verify?

Comment: First check if you initialize data something like: `...data: EbayDataService...`

Comment: @MishaMashina - Yes, in my component I have   data: EbayDataService | undefined

Comment: Do you have the full interface of EbayDataService? Can you paste it? I guess it's almost like @Antoniossss wrote: `data[0].searchResult[0].item[0].title`, but nothing can be certain until we see the EbayDataService structure.

Comment: @MishaMashina Sure thing. I just pasted the entire response into the original question

Comment: @MishaMashina I think you're onto something with 'data[0]'  - If I try data[0].findItemsbyKeywordsResponse, I don't get the "doesn't exist on service" error any more

Comment: First I dont think that `data` is a `service` of any kind. Second, since you are not using any typing `this.httpClient.get` there is no reason to use it up the caller chain as it is a pure fiction anyway.

Comment: It would be useful if you can console.log(data) before assigning data to this.data, just to be sure of the structure of the response.

Comment: @MishaMashina When I try that, I just get the output: [object Object]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that

```
const data={complete_json_you_have_provided}

//then

console.log(data.findItemsByKeywordsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item[0].title);
```

prints required title array `[Apple iPhone 12 mini (5G) Factory Unlocked GSM+CDMA 256GB | 128GB | 64GB]`

check here [TS PLAYGROUND](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=177&ssc=80&pln=177&pc=1#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAEwIYyQXgN7DnARAMwEsIEBJGAUwFsoAhATwGkL6B3MAJwSgCUKoADpCgVcALjgBtbDjhZZs3EhABrcVJkKcuAMoBXECH5Rcm2QF0ANGe0A3ChyiFI66VsUBGAHQeAzF4AGU3crGzwYQip%20VCoBVzDtACYAxMSAWgDfDN8AFQ8ANjEPRLEA-K9UgIAtYK1Q91wRJA4QAAs%20KD0AGxh49xx5fu0AAXA9CF6JXA9cayHtQkoqPvmBhP7cRepSBBXVhVxEgE4AFgB2AA58-LOAVl8ji9r9uHqX8MWu0Qk3d%200AQQEAi%20cEIAAVWpAKHBinAqMRCHAABS3ADiAEo4AAxZQwTj0OAAVQgXTAqgoCDgqJ0AFkANQAYQAIjT-nBErd8qjaHAAD4wxIXbl8uD5E7c577N4vXAAc1JACMkF0dnt3rgAKK0f4ATTShJ0ktW0v2jT0CoiMC%20aplgBJyBmtChIATROAAeRJxGhtqxPA1GrgOgAEqQwWDSAA5VFwH1%20gN%20nKEngRmMGwMagAyGY1PCN8xNq1wAg4kWa9AZKAosvxNv2gz%202hAlerHHoqp%206xlR18t1ueZeBfVTcoLfoEaQUVrf1wDIoXS6cAhUKgcAAZIGqM0YAJIRB%20P2pZ3%20gBfI8KQdDOXKr6tpMZqfzXCtGDbqBiAD078IXgoSvokVlLxwCod8YFaPQqAVKAv03WV%20HfWV31aWgdX%20f43R0VgAD8AEdWllegLioVF3ygNIug8E4Ai8AArARZQPEI5nVWxCAoVhyGoO8H0vZ9Xw-d9WCEn8-yAsAQMWEDAWBCg0nBXdZOKNJ4QgQg0jRNIcRAPFW31EkyRUCk0mpGk0mZVk0g5LlaDSYohRssVuTSd9jnOK4bnuR4AH5bGaNBbm7DxbkuM4jg8M5EkYupmJlJA9DxMEkHoHiNhgDg9FEM8LBi00hFgZUGTABBvg0Bs8A8YoACpKqi88csLUlh2cCAUoaWgODAMAVC6egIEsCMdUsA1-lq7KssbMBxjS5KOzK3ADVGnALw2KBWkIIFiFlUgIHwMBWq0esG0aNaNogWUdAcVijEK2B9qGQ6ypGEA9A4DgKAgEA212KYDSZWZxsfAB9QHfK6DLgfUXBqKCAH3FPR7Xnq9VVvWgRNpyegXTujYsTezKEeWwsUYEHIwAzMkUGakxZoRvAAHVOC6BBWEIYrFui2HFAoAAPF0EC2BAdBOtGzuxho0oy9m6s57QoSZJKhdRzb-l8wguiQBVrRphHcAl-HHsJx9WiQEgunRyISt%20HWZhl15Ofh95DYOER502nRUBgPRqdKhsHqHF63omMESyMMWDttg5RgD97PvbPBfv%202nFGB0HwcByGTgeLwLieCO4AdsqnY2cAIHsDhKAQBlo6DkPLbzv25qj16Y6%20yGE6RuaU%20VNOM6znOpa0AuGyLhoXbNs73crMODn%20bTCHsAelo700IiiDMKHwSYfZ1sFBSZHIjiDW5Ehpe5DVt8x7YBke8DN2BNu23aw4b00FWiN18HwBwNQgDWvm%207ej0CDKhEIvRGttcAKj0G2GAEYwCsBVkgNWf865J2AV0UBF9l5E1QOXHIFtp6KGSKkDI6QAgeByCkUotwxC3AuIEAI1QwE3wOO9BA%20DJzayAcQshJwMgUKoQEE4tCjgMKYVgiBd8IhnQxljLhc0sSEG5hSYOhBQ4SJ1rKQgm9CHaHwCA-WhdsGPlYCgNohUpq6LwIkfIzCr5-BvrgN6nsODQFnkYAQFcw663SoYqUxiDgl35hEFw8i6wQKCYsZqccrZAKCow5hATi6QGCc1JkhBBDqzHBOVBtNcBuhdBAOACowDczsWVIexokkLCgDSboEQABqzRCCU0gBmDJ0iGJhMLHrdmji8QCB4JWBA7T76i26Y%20Xp18sqVLqOsWZg4ixIC0b-EJEA3TxQEPFB8L9tACGWRQCMEE34cH2tMKKhtcDvTSmxKAYIHCJTgmcm2VSjy6zAKgLojz9wTIOHZKyiRfAXOMe8z5P8bk-MAZef5nJAUXPmWERZWwqAXWaG0biEynwvgEG%20T8QlWAiSSmJECUA2hfi8M%20KgXQvKAwgCoVgaB5JQlXIDBACAwBoA8Cy9aspOUsvohATleZL4KAdpfU8oBhBgC%20F4UksokTIFQF4IgJBOI0AYMwNgnBuAdCENACgkgAjmC8E0Fo7R%20D1MNca5FVqvCWi%20OiAA3EAA)

Comment: Hmm...I must be doing something fundamentally wrong.

Comment: What I don't understand is why {{ data | json }} outputs the entire JSON to the screen, but I can't seem to access it the way that you've demonstrated should work.

Comment: `json` pipe just serializes java object to a string similarly to what JSON.stringify would do (probably internally it is calling just that, never checked)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why (please help educate me if you know), but I got it working by changing the sendGetRequest() function to:

```
  public sendGetRequest(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.REST_API_SERVER);
  }
```

Rather than:

```
 public sendGetRequest(): Observable<any> {
   return this.httpClient.get(this.REST_API_SERVER);
  }
```